# Selecting * from Hive Temporary Table Immediately after creating the Temporary Table Not Working

Tags: hive, sas

I am trying to create some temporary tables to grab most recent partitions and then inner join back on to main table to filter out older partitions. To do this, I would much rather prefer to use temporary tables rather than tons of nested subqueries. I am using tools such as SAS via pass-through proc sql to connect to the db and query the data.

Example:

```
proc sql;
CONNECT TO ODBC (USER=XXXXX PASSWORD="XXXXX" DSN="XXXXX");

CREATE TABLE max_partition as SELECT * FROM CONNECTION TO ODBC
(
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp1 as select MAX(partitiondate) as latestpartitiondate, id FROM tbl1 GROUP BY id;

select * from tmp1
);
quit;
```

I get errors around missing EOF by 'select' if I do not include the semicolon and I get an error if I do use the semicolon (as I have shown in the above example).

```
CLI prepare error: [Hortonworks][Hardy] (80) Syntax or semantic analysis error thrown in server while executing query. Error message
       from server: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:148 cannot recognize input near 'id' ';' ')'
```

I am trying to use temp tables in various tools such as Proc sql in SAS as well as pyodbc in Python. I still receive the same errors. I simply want to be able to generate a table of max partitions for that particular ID and then select from that temp table altogether in a single pass through statement.

Comment: Are you firing SQLs correctly ? it seems to be a syntax error. it seems its not liking column `id`. Can you enclose the id column with backquote while firing  it?

Comment: Can you show your full SQL Pass through code?

Comment: Removed the python tags as this seems to have no relation to python. If you re-add the python tags, please also add your Python code.

Comment: remove parentheses, they do nothing useful: `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp1 as select MAX(partitiondate) as latestpartitiondate, id FROM tbl1 GROUP BY id;`

Comment: @Reeza Updated post.

Comment: You cannot run two statements via FROM CONNECTION TO .  If you want to run other statements then use EXECUTE BY instead.  Then you can run your SELECT as a second SAS statement.

Comment: @Tom The error is the same in other tools such as Python. It is not specific to SAS proc sql.

Comment: Because the issue is the same, you cannot pass multiple commands at once. Did you test if your commands work directly on your Hive system?

Answer (score 3):

The normal way is to run the prerequisite statements first and then run the query.

```
EXECUTE BY ODBC
(
  CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp1 as 
  select MAX(partitiondate) as latestpartitiondate
       , id 
  FROM tbl1 
  GROUP BY id
);
CREATE TABLE max_partition as SELECT * FROM CONNECTION TO ODBC
(
  select * from tmp1
);
```

Does that not work with HIVE?

Answer (score 2):

In SAS proc sql, you can't do what you're doing - but you also don't need to, unless Hive has something very different from any other ODBC connection.

```
proc sql;
CONNECT TO ODBC (USER=XXXXX PASSWORD="XXXXX" DSN="XXXXX");

CREATE TABLE max_partition as SELECT * FROM CONNECTION TO ODBC
(
select MAX(partitiondate) as latestpartitiondate, id FROM tbl1 GROUP BY id;
);
quit;
```

If you do need to create the temporary table, you'd have to do it in an `execute ( ) by connection to odbc`, which should be possible (I've done something similar with SQL Server, so as long as SAS and Hive implement ODBC connections in the same way it should be okay) and then in a following statement do the `select` from it.

Comment: Thanks. I understand that the above statement would work. However, if I need to write multiple Hive queries (lets say I am joining multiple tables that have different MAX(partitiondate)) I would not be able to query a SAS CREATE TABLE in the middle of a pass through statement to Hive since the SAS table created above would be stored in my SAS work library. E.g. I would need to run it all in one pass through to grab and join all the tables that have different partitiondates to the original table).

Comment: Then show what you want to do that you can't do this way, and we can help you there.  In general you can't do a sequence that way - you need to do them separately.  You can do one large query though, just can't have the create table in the same block.  `SELECT * FROM CONNECTION TO ODBC` needs to contain one `SELECT`.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM CONNECTION TO ODBC ( SELECT A,B,C FROM TBL1 LEFT JOIN ( SELECT * FROM TBL2) TBL2 ON TBL1.ID = TBL2.ID LEFT JOIN TBL3 ON TBL1.ID=TBL3.ID` etc. is fine, and you can also use `with` CTE's as `leftjoin` notes which is fine also.

Comment: What makes you think it needs to be all in one pass through, are your temp tables disappearing once your query is done?

Comment: @Reeza I have multiple hadoop tables that have IDs with different partition brevity. That means that the most recent partition table for ID #1 is different across Tbl #1 and Tbl #2. For this reason, I am finding the most recent partition date for each ID within each table and then filtering out the older partitions via an inner join of the max partition "temp table" on the original table itself. To do this I need to create a table of the ID with it's max partition for that particular table, then use this in a connection via a pass-through query.

Comment: @Coldchain9 I think you could do it in one query easily - with a CTE or a subquery or a join - but really you can go either way, it's okay to make the temporary tables as Tom shows in his answer or I mention at the end of this one, or use a CTE.  You just can't do it all inside one `select`, that's all.

Answer (score 0):

[Some drivers may not support multiple sql statements in single session.](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/Hive-JDBC-drivers-support-to-execute-multiple-SQL-Statements/td-p/79630)

**As a workaround, use permanent table loaded in separate session (insert overwrite) and reused in other sessions**. Temp teble does not give you any improvement comparing with permanent one except it gets automatically dropped at the end and it can not be reused in different sessions.

Also WITH (CTE) or simple subquery in the FROM works faster than temp table if table is not reused. WITH can be materialized and reused multiple times in the same query.

Comment: The `()` are needed by the SAS syntax that's passing the query down - but you're probably right that it won't support the two statements the way he did them.